# How to check cookie in umbraco?

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I want to check cookie in umbraco , is it possible or not ?

If yes then how can i set cookie in template and can retrive cookie's value in template or xslt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the built in Library to do this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:RequestCookies('cookie')" />
```

Add that to your XSLT and you can call the macro from any pages in your site.

Just to complete the answer you would use

```
<xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:setCookie('cookie')" />
```

to set the value and the above code to get the value.

Comment: Just to complete the answer you would use <xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:setCookie('cookie')" /> to set the value and the above code to get the value.

Comment: @JohnC, how exactly do you do this in Umbraco?